# wait() does not free all current locks, how it can be done?

Tags: java, multithreading

According to Java doc, when `obj1.wait()` happens, "The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies..."

So, the lock of obj1 is freed, while the current thread is waiting. But what about all other locks? It is possible, that the piece of the code is locking two objects:

```
synchronized(obj2){
    f1();
    synchronized(obj1){
        f2();
        obj1.wait();
    }
}
```

Obj2 won't be freed, but the thread does not run, another thread will wait for freeing of obj2 in vain...  I don't understand the reason of that continuing locking of obj2. But OK, it is as it is.

But how can I organize this waiting better, how can I unlock for the time of waiting all or at least several current locks?

Comment: I don't have my JCIP book handy, so I can't say what the recommended fix is, but I suspect you'll have to exit all synchronized blocks manually to release the lock(s).

Comment: @markspace according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait(), the object for which you are calling wait(), is released. No need for leaving.

Comment: Except it appears that `obj2` won't be, so that's why you need to leave to release the lock.

Comment: Instead of using a monitor lock you could use implementations of the [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) and [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) interface. If `obj2` was a `Lock` you could release it before waiting for `obj1`.

Comment: @markspace yes, I am interested in obj2. So, the solution is not to use wait() in the code, covered by more than one synchronization? And no Locks or Futures or something else helps? Maybe the use of something else than wait() could help?

Comment: thats kinda how locking works in any language... you should avoid holding multiple locks at the same time id say!?

Comment: if you cant do that: the synchronized statement is a bit 'simple' I guess... go with what @Marcono1234 suggested :)

Comment: @Marcono1234 Oh, yes, Condition! It could be useful. Could you write an answer with an example? I would gladly recognize it. Not for me, but for later readers.

Comment: @Gangnus, the answer I added does not use a `Condition` because for your example this does not seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html)s and [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)s which are more flexible than `sychronized` statements.

For your example you could replace `obj2` with a `ReentrantLock`:

```
Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

try {
    // Blocks until the lock is acquired, just like a `synchronized` statement
    lock2.lock();
    f1();

    synchronized (obj1) {
        f2();
        lock2.unlock();
        obj1.wait();
        lock2.lock();
    }
}
// Use `finally` to make sure the lock is always released, even if an exception is thrown
finally {
    // Exception might have been thrown before current thread could acquire lock again, cannot 
    // unlock then
    if (lock2.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
        lock2.unlock();
    }
}
```

However, this would allow another thread to acquire `lock2` before the current thread starting waiting for `obj1`. If this is not desired you could replace `obj1` with a `Lock` instead and wait for `obj2`.

Comment: Thank you, it is even more simple. But I think that the source problem appears because of use of different layers for multithreading. wait/notify - synchronized - Lock/Condition. The pure Lock/Condition solution will be better, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

> But what about all other locks?...  I don't understand the reason of that continuing locking of obj2

Neither the Java compiler nor the run-time library can not know whether it is *safe* to unlock obj2.  The entire reason for locking objects is to prevent other threads from seeing shared data in an inconsistent state.  The only reason why you would ever write `synchronized (obj2) {...}` is that your program is going to do something while `obj2` is locked that should be hidden from every other thread except the one that is doing it.

It is the programmer's responsibility to know when the mess has been cleaned up and its safe to unlock the lock.  The compiler can't do that for you.

---

So why, you might ask, does `obj1.wait()` unlock `obj1`?  That's because, if you use `wait()` and `notify()` in the way that they are intended to be used, the unlock has to be atomic with the waiting.  There has to be no way that some other thread could slip in and deliver an `obj1.notify()` in between the moment when the first thread unlocks `obj1`, and the moment when it enters the wait state.  If that was possible, then the notification could be lost, and the program would hang.

You can learn all about why `wait()` and `notify()` work the way they do and, how they are supposed to be used by reading through Oracle's "Guarded Blocks" tutorial.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: You think that this thread, during waiting with obj1, can change something? It is doing nothing, with any data. It is only waiting for notification or timeout.

Comment: @Gangnus, No. I don't think that. `obj1` and `obj2` are different objects.  There is no strong reason why `obj1.wait()` _should_ unlock `obj2`, and what I tried to say above is that there _are_ strong reasons why it should _not_ unlock `obj2`. Also worth noting: The Java language compiler and run time library are not as smart as you are. They can not know as much as you know about how your code works---about what is safe and what is not safe. They err on the side of safety, and not unlocking `obj2` is safer than unlocking it.